# (saved) event is getting triggered twice in HTML

Tags: html, asp.net, typescript

I am working on ASP.Net project. My frontend page has 1 editable field.
When user edits data in the field, saved event trigger method. It is getting triggered twice so data entry is getting added twice in database.
.html -

```
      <cool-inline-edit-field
        name="homePhone"
        [ngModel]="user.homePhone"
        (saved)="saveUserHomePhoneAsync($event)"
        required
        pattern="[0-9]{10}"
      >
      </cool-inline-edit-field>
```

component.ts

```
  saveUserHomePhoneAsyc($event: Event) {
    this.showSpinner();
    debugger;
    const oldVal = this.user.homePhone;
    const newVal = $event as unknown as keyof any;
    debugger;
    this.accountService.setBorrowerPreferencesChangeData(this.borrowerIdentityData.fullName, "HomePhone", 
      oldVal, newVal.toString()).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.hideSpinner();
        this.user.homePhone = newVal.toString();
        this.snackbarService.show("Value saved");
           },
      (error) => { 
        this.user.homePhone = oldVal;
       this.hideSpinner(); 
        this.showError('Failed to save home phone. Please try again');
        console.log(error);
      }      
    );
  }
```

I am not getting why it is getting called twice? .ts method should run only once.

Comment: Show us the content of the component **cool-inline-edit-field**

Comment: @FolabiAhn - Its the Angular package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-cool/inline-edit-field

Comment: Are you preventing end-users clicking it multiple times and sending multiple events?

Comment: Nope. I am no controlling anything for user. I want only 1 even should get triggered instead of 1

Comment: This is coming from the package. Create a issue on github

Comment: ooohhh. So its not in my hand then. I will create issue for them. Also will look for other option for inline edit.